# Simulate distortion of guitar amplifier on byte array

Tags: java, math, audio, filtering, simulation

If I(in Java) have a `double[]` array containing audio samples, ranging from -1 to 1, which I can play, and have generated to sound like a guitar string being played, is there any way through which I can simulate the effect of distortion from an amplifier on these samples?

I apologize for the vagueness of the term "distortion", but I'm referring to any effect similar to setting a guitar amplifier to "distortion". What I already have sounds like an acoustic guitar, or an electric guitar with no distortion(set to "clean"), so how can I alter the array to sound more like what you would expect from an electric guitar in a rock or metal setting?

The current set of samples is calculated using the following method:

```
double[] samples = new double[duration]; //duration = seconds * sampleRate
int period = (float)sampleRate / (float)frequency;
double[] buf = new double[period]; //a ring buffer used for the sound generation
int count = 0, c1 = 1, c2 = 2;
for(int i=0; i<duration; i++){
    if(count <= period)count = 0;
    if(c1 <= period)c1 = 0;
    if(c2 <= period)c2 = 0;
    if(i < period){
        buf[count] = rand.nextDouble() * 2 - 1; //rand being a Random
    }
    else{
        buff[count] = (buff[c1] + buff[c2]) / 2;
    }
    samples[i] = buff[count];
    count++;
    c1++;
    c2++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three main types of distortion:

- Hard distortion: simple clipping of the signal

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < duration; i++)
  {
      double sample = samples[i] * gain_pre;
      if (sample > clip)
          sample = clip;
      else
      if (sample < -clip)
          sample = -clip;
      samples[i] = sample * gain_post;
  }
  ```
- Normal distortion: exponential smooth scaling of the signal

  ```
  double max = 1.0 / (1.0 - exp(-gain_pre));
  for (int i = 0; i < duration; i++)
  {
      double sample = samples[i] * gain_pre;
      double z = (sample < 0.0) ? (-1.0 + exp(sample)) :
                                  (1.0 - exp(-sample));   
      samples[i] = z * max * gain_post;
  }
  ```
- Soft distortion: same as above, but using arc-tan (presumably more aggressive)

  ```
  double max = 1.0 / atan(gain_pre);
  for (int i = 0; i < duration; i++)
  {
      samples[i] = atan(samples[i] * gain_pre) * max * gain_post;
  }
  ```

Variables:

- `gain_pre` and `gain_post`: Pre-gain and Post-gain parameters
- `clip`: maximum value for hard-distortion signal
- `samples`: the sample sequence you calculate

References / more info:

http://cp-gfx.sourceforge.net/ (download the source code and look in /src/effects/)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_(music)#Theory_and_circuits

Comment: Thanks. I'd figured out the hard distortion after messing around with it, and I think that's more like what I was going for. Also adding high/low pass/boost filters helped.

Comment: actually, there is something strange. I don't know why but applying the hard distortion in the function that generates the sound sounds very different from doing it in another function later.

Comment: @user2649681 because the hard distortion introduces flat-tops in the signal pattern, which are similar spectrally to square waves - many odd-frequency harmonics appear in addition to the original frequencies. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave#Examining_the_square_wave

Comment: I know how the hard distortion works, but what I mean is if in the function I generate the signal, I also apply hard distortion when converting the `double[]` to `short[]`(multiply by 32767), it sound very different from doing the distortion to the `short[]` in a later function.

Comment: @user2649681 I think you maybe overflowing the `short` datatype, when multiplying it by one of the gain factors. Cast each sample to `int` before you process it.